# How can I prevent an SSRS report from being emailed multiple times when an external domain is on the distribution list?

Tags: reporting-services

We have several SSRS subscriptions and the only reports that are emailed twice are the three different reports that have external domains on the distribution list. With that said, the three reports with external domains on the distribution list are not always emailed twice. It has duplicated about 80-90% of the time since the issue began a few weeks ago. Prior to the issue appearing, these same reports ran correctly for over a year. Also, the duplicate reports go out at virtually the same time (a few seconds apart).

I have made sure the jobs are not actually running twice. I have also checked the badmail folder and nothing is being logged in there, as I thought maybe the emails were "failing," despite us still receiving them, causing them to send again.

Yesterday, I created a subscription that had three different domains (one internal and two external) and the report was emailed out three times, which is a first. It's obviously a small sample size but leads me to believe it may send out once for each unique domain on the distribution list.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Kyle

Comment: Since you have already checked that the job was executed only once, you can be sure that SSRS has forwarded the email only once. Your email server will use "biforkation" to send the email to multiple domains. If one recipient has addresses in multiple (external) domains and the report is emailed to both addresses, that recipient will receive the report twice. If this isn't the reason for your issue, there must be a configuration problem in your mailing infrastructure.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Wolfgang. To clarify, all recipients on the distribution list receive the duplicate emails, whether they have an internal or external domain. I believe the external domains have something to do with the duplicate emails, simply because 1) the only reports that duplicate are the ones that have external domains and 2) the reports containing only internal domains have never duplicated. I just don't know why that is or what to check next so I'm hoping that observation may narrow it down and trigger an idea from someone who has more experience in this area than I do.

Comment: I'm sure that the duplication has nothing to do with Reporting Services. I suggest to contact you email service administrators (of the mail server that is specified in Reporting Services Configuration Manager) for further investigations.